Onclick event not working in Blazor Web Assembly 8.0
I am studying a Blazor course and I noticed the button click event does not trigger on button click. I created a simple Blazor web assembly 8.0 project to confirm the issue. I noticed on button click nothing happened.
I added @rendermode InteractiveServer to my test page and also these  methods to my program.cs, but nothing happened.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents()

app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

Program.cs
using BlazorApp1.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents();
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();

var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
  app.UseHsts();
}

app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>();
app.Run();

Test.razor
@page "/test"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
<h3>Test JavaScript Interop</h3>
<button type="button" @onclick="TestJsInterop">Click Me</button>

@code {
  private async Task TestJsInterop()
  {
    // Call the custom JS function showCustomAlert
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showCustomAlert", "Hello from custom JS interop!");
  }
}

window.showCustomAlert = function (message) {
  alert(message); // This is the native JS alert function
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BlazorApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <!-- The component rendered in InteractiveServer mode will be mounted here -->
    </app>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="js/spp.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

The weird part is that the counter button works perfectly well in the counter page.
I also Updated Routes element in App.razor file with <Routes @rendermode=RenderMode.InteractiveServer /> and <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
I want the button click event to display an alert with message "Hello from custom JS interop!"
Please help me fix this error as I can't forge ahead with my Blazor tutorial.

This is not "a Blazor web assembly 8.0 project".  Be more precise about the project type (template choice and settings).

It is ,that is what i chose when creating the project

You say "Blazor web assembly 8.0 project" then start adding @rendermode InteractiveServer .  Whatever course you're following, either it isn't taking you to the right places, or you're off piste. You're mixing up Server and Web Assembly without knowing what you're doing and creating a right dog's breakfast.  "Please help me fix this error as I can't forge ahead with my Blazor tutorial."  Follow the tutorial, or chose another that works!

Blazor 8 offers "Web App" and "Webassembly standalone app". You are mixing these two and maybe some pre-version8 stuff. Best thing is to start this project again, from scratch.

I chose Blazor Web App when creating the project.I  applied @rendermode InteractiveServer when the onclick event was not firing. based on some suggestions here on stackoverflow

Well, the JS related code looks Ok so you broke something else. Starting again is still  the best option. Pay anttention to all the checkboxes in the Create Project dialogs.

Try with <script src="./js/spp.js"></script> and rebuild the project.

@ Qiang Fu,i did that ,It didn't  work.

There are two Visual Studio project templates, which can refer to a .NET 8 Blazor WebAssembly App:

A Blazor Web App with WebAssembly render mode. This project template was introduced with .NET 8.
A Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App. This project template existed before .NET 8, but didn't have "Standalone" in its name.

The provided code snippets don't make sense for any of the two project templates. For example:

The Blazor Web App doesn't include an index.html file in any of its variations. Similar content exists in a file Components/App.razor:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


A Blazor Web App with WebAssembly render mode doesn't use AddInteractiveServerComponents() or AddInteractiveServerRenderMode(). Instead, it should have this code in Program.cs:

using BlazorApp1.Client.Pages;
using BlazorApp1.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(BlazorApp1.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.Run();


The index.html file of a Blazor WebAssembly (Standalone) App has a  <script> tag that loads blazor.webassembly.js and not blazor.server.js.


I chose Blazor Web App when creating the project.

If this is true, then I assume that you created a Blazor Web App with incorrect render mode and/or Per page / component interactivity location. For apps with WebAssembly render mode this means that only .razor files in the Client project with @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly will support @onclick, JSInterop or any other interactivity. The @rendermode declaration was missing in Test.razor, and maybe you added some other unnecessary stuff while troubleshooting and using an old or confusing Blazor tutorial for a different app type.
Currently, the app is probably in a messy and invalid state, which makes it easier for you to start from scratch. My recommendation is to create A Blazor Web App with WebAssembly render mode and Global interactivity location. Then, add Test.razor to the Pages folder in the Client project:
@page "/test"

@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<h3>Test JavaScript Interop</h3>

<button type="button" @onclick="TestJsInterop">Click Me</button>

<script suppress-error="BL9992">
    window.showCustomAlert = function (message) {
        alert(message); // This is the native JS alert function
    }
</script>

@code {
    private async Task TestJsInterop()
    {
        // Call the custom JS function showCustomAlert
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showCustomAlert", "Hello from custom JS interop!");
    }
}

This should work.

Thank you so much@dimodi
